# Aurelia breakpoint isn't in the right place

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I have a problem with the aurelia skeleton-typescript-webpack project.
When I want to debug the typescript code in chrome, the breakpoints and the place where the program actually stops, is off.
Here is an example:

[image]

Here I placed a debugger statement in line 18, but chrome stopped in line 23. It seems if it stopped in the correct place, because "i" has a value but "a" doesn't.

Any idea, how can I solve this?

As I mentioned i'm using the skeleton-typescript-webpack project. I changed nothing, except line 17, 18, 19. I'm running the application with the "npm run webpack-dev-server" command. 
Node version is v6.9.1, npm version is 4.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't fix my issue, so I switched back to an earlier version, and it's working now.